# How does Infection Bio War calculate infection spreading (infecting)?

Tags: infection-bio-war-free

I was playing Infection Bio War, but it certainly has a different way of calculating how the infection expands than other games in the genre. When you open the stats tab while all states are infected, the game shows you like 10x more states with over 90% or under 10% infected people then the other states.

**How do the infections spread from across countries?

How does this differ from how the infection spreads inside a state?**

Comment: Why did you re-ask this?  If you want more attention for an existing question, you should bounty it, not re-ask it.

Comment: @Frank I don't want the attention but activity - otherwise the question is not visible. :D Also, congrats for your 17,791th downvote :P

Comment: Yeah, that's what bounties are for. We frown on users reasking questions. There wasn't even anything wrong with yours.

Comment: The other question was since deleted by the looks of it so this "question" is valid unless it can be restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some in-game testing and file opening, I can give these results:

**Infection spreading across countries:**

- If in a country 50% or more percent of the live people are infected (this number starts at 50% in most states, but may move from 30% to 60% and is different country to country), the infection will spread to all surrounding countries, which will have 1 more infected person.
- The percentual limit of people needed for infection spreading to the surrounding states may vary due to: purchased upgrades, country climate (temperature, driness), wealthiness, percent of dead people.
- All states which have an airport or a dock have a chance of sending a plane/boat with an infected passenger. This chance is equal to the percent of infected people in that country.
- When a boat/plane is sent, it does not change the number of people in the state it was sent from, nor of the state it lands in.
- If an infected boat/plane lands in any country, it infects 1 healthy person from that country (if there is any).
- Countries without live people can't infect nearby states nor send ships/airplanes.

**Infection sprreading inside a state:**

- Every game tick (about one second) the number of infected people is recalculated by this formula:

  I(new) = I + (I * H * v) / A

  where I stands forr Infected, H for Healthy, A for Alive and v is the variable.

  - The variable v is a number from 0 to 1. It is affected by purchased upgrades, number of infected surrounding states, country climate, wealthiness and urbanity and is different in every state. At the beginning of the game it is in between 0.1 and 0.2 in all countries, but can change rapidly. The number can't exceed 1.0.